# Basic PHP SQL Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

We have a basic PHP script to extract the title and description for each job from a MySQL database as simply display this information. This is what it looks like:

```
$sql        = "SELECT `title`, `desc` FROM jobs WHERE active = 'y'";
$query      = mysql_query($sql) or die('<em><strong>SQL Error:</strong> ' . mysql_error() . '</em>');
$results    = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$results['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$results['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

Now, this only extracts one row from the database, but it should extract two. So, I tried the following to replace the `while` statement:

```
<?php foreach($results as $result) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$result['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$result['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

This statement doesn't work either. This just displays (weirdly) the first character of each column in the first row in the table.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this isn't working as it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result variable you have used is `result` not `results`

Replace

```
$sql        = "SELECT `title`, `desc` FROM jobs WHERE active = 'y'";
$query      = mysql_query($sql) or die('<em><strong>SQL Error:</strong> ' . mysql_error() . '</em>');
**$results    = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);** // remove this line

<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$results['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$results['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

to

```
$sql        = "SELECT `title`, `desc` FROM jobs WHERE active = 'y'";
$query      = mysql_query($sql) or die('<em><strong>SQL Error:</strong> ' . mysql_error() . '</em>');


<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$result['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$result['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

Comment: Head-desk. Thanks so much, don't know how I missed that.  $results was only in there still from experimentation… Can only kick myself for not deleting it straight away as then I would have spotted it for myself.

Answer (score 3):

In your `while` use same variable `$result` as you started:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$result['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$result['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and remove the first `$results    = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);`

Answer (score 1):

You already fetched the first row before your loop started, which is why it only prints the second row. Simply comment out that line:

```
#$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); # here is your first row, 
                                       # simply comment this line

<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$result['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$result['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

You are also looping over `$result` but using `$results` in your while loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$sql        = "SELECT `title`, `desc` FROM jobs WHERE active = 'y'";
$query      = mysql_query($sql) or die('<em><strong>SQL Error:</strong> ' . mysql_error() . '</em>');


<?php 
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="left_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">';
    echo "<h2>{$result['title']}</h2>";
    echo "<p>{$result['desc']}</p>";
    echo '</div>';
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

to

```
<?php while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```